# Paperclip attachments not deleting URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am using paperclip in my model. This model has a file attached called `avatar`. When I use `avatar.delete` the file remains linked. Rather than replacing the image with the default image I've set in the model, as I result I get a broken link image. I've tried manually resetting the fields to nil and removing all folders and files associated with the paperclip attachment, but I'm still getting broken links.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been doing when deleting images

```
@model.avatar.destroy #Will remove the attachment and save the model
@model.avatar.clear #Will queue the attachment to be deleted


class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar

  before_save :destroy_avatar?

  def avatar_delete
    @avatar_delete ||= "0"
  end

  def avatar_delete=(value)
    @avatar_delete = value
  end

private
  def destroy_image?
    self.avatar.clear if @image_avatar == "1"
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps you